# html / javascript onclick function with time

Tags: javascript, html

I would like that when clicking on my label I would execute a javascript function that would return the exact time of that click, with hours, minutes and seconds.
I have a javascript function that does what I want, but when I click on the label, nothing appears to me. Am I doing something wrong?

```js
function getTime() {
    const timeNow = new Date();
    const hours = timeNow.getHours();
    const minutes = timeNow.getMinutes();
    const seconds = timeNow.getSeconds();
    let timeString = '' + ((hours > 24) ? hours - 12 : hours);
    timeString += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes;
    timeString += ((seconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + seconds;
    timeString += (hours >= 12) ? "" : "";
    return timeString;
}

const hoursSpan = document.getElementById('hours');
hoursSpan.textContent = getTime();
```

```html
<div class="wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100 validate-input">
    <span class="label-input100">Date</span>
    <input class="input100" onclick="getTime()" id="hours" name="Date" placeholder="Date">
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `hoursSpan` declaration and usage should be *inside* `getTime()` (although once done, the function better be renamed)

Comment: Your use of getElementById is outside the function you call, it won't be executed. Also not that `language="JavaScript"` has been obsolete for many years, you are probably working to very old tutorials.

Comment: because you do not set the text to anything that is returned.... you just call the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<input>` elements donot have `textContent` you should change `value`.Set your `onclick` event to another `function` which would change `value` on each click. 
You can also add the following line in `getTime()` to get rid of other `changeTime()`

```
hoursSpan.textContent = getTime();
```

```js
const hoursSpan = document.getElementById('hours');
function getTime() {
        const timeNow = new Date();
        const hours = timeNow.getHours();
        const minutes = timeNow.getMinutes();
        const seconds = timeNow.getSeconds();
        let timeString = '' + ((hours > 24) ? hours - 12 : hours);
        timeString += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes;
        timeString += ((seconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + seconds;
        timeString += (hours >= 12) ? "" : "";
        return timeString;
    }

function changeTime(){
  hoursSpan.value = getTime();
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100 validate-input">
    <span class="label-input100">Date</span>
    <input class="input100" onclick="changeTime()" id="hours" name="Date" placeholder="Date">
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
 </div>
```

Comment: I need to wait 3 minutes

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100 validate-input">
    <span class="label-input100">Date</span>
    <!-- this reference is passed to the called function -->
    <input class="input100" onclick="getTime(this)" id="hours" name="Date" placeholder="Date">
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
 </div>
```

JavaScript: (assign timestring to value property of input field instead of textContext property)

```
<script language="JavaScript">

    function getTime(self) {
        const timeNow = new Date();
        const hours = timeNow.getHours();
        const minutes = timeNow.getMinutes();
        const seconds = timeNow.getSeconds();
        let timeString = '' + ((hours > 24) ? hours - 12 : hours);
        timeString += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes;
        timeString += ((seconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + seconds;
        timeString += (hours >= 12) ? "" : "";
        // Assign timeString to value property
        self.value = timeString;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the time displaying too inside the getTime function

```
function getTime() {
     const timeNow = new Date();
     const hours = timeNow.getHours();
     const minutes = timeNow.getMinutes();
     const seconds = timeNow.getSeconds();
     let timeString = '' + ((hours > 24) ? hours - 12 : hours);
     timeString += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes;
     timeString += ((seconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + seconds;
     timeString += (hours >= 12) ? "" : "";


     const hoursSpan = document.getElementById('hours');
     hoursSpan.textContent = timeString;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the most likely issue here is that you're using `const` as a variable declarator in vanilla JS. Your browser might not know how to properly handle it, and thus it breaks. Your code is working [online here (CodePen)](https://codepen.io/darrylhuffman/pen/xBXKZK?editors=1010) when it's compiled with Babel.
Perhaps change your code to:

```
function getTime() {
    var timeNow = new Date();
    var hours = timeNow.getHours();
    var minutes = timeNow.getMinutes();
    var seconds = timeNow.getSeconds();
    var timeString = '' + ((hours > 24) ? hours - 12 : hours);
    timeString += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes;
    timeString += ((seconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + seconds;
    timeString += (hours >= 12) ? "" : "";
    return timeString;
}

var hoursSpan = document.getElementById('hours');
hoursSpan.textContent = getTime();
```

Having the document.getElementById outside of getTime is not an issue.

**EDIT**

I didn't realize you were setting the value of an input, simply change:

```
const hoursSpan = document.getElementById('hours');
hoursSpan.textContent = getTime();
```

To:

```
const hoursSpan = document.getElementById('hours');
hoursSpan.value = getTime();
```

I'd like to add though, if you are going to use Let/Const Declarations, I'd recommend you compile your code with something like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) so that it works across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `value` & not `textContent`

```js
function getTime() {
  const timeNow = new Date();
  const hours = timeNow.getHours();
  const minutes = timeNow.getMinutes();
  const seconds = timeNow.getSeconds();
  let timeString = '' + ((hours > 24) ? hours - 12 : hours);
  timeString += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes;
  timeString += ((seconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + seconds;
  timeString += (hours >= 12) ? "" : "";
  let hoursSpan = document.getElementById('hoursCon');
  hoursSpan.value = timeString;
  return timeString;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100 validate-input">
  <span class="label-input100">Date</span>
  <input class="input100" onclick="getTime()" id="hoursCon" name="Date" placeholder="Date">
  <span class="focus-input100"></span>
</div>
```